# Yii Autocomplete rendered as normal input

Tags: autocomplete, yii

I am getting strange results with an autocomplete widget:

On my local server, it's working fine: autocomplete suggestions pop up as expected, with HTML as:

```
<input id="WzExt01" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" 
 name="WzExt01" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" 
 aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

... but on my live server, with the same source code, the field is rendered without the autocomplete tags:

```
<input id="WzExt01" type="text" name="WzExt01">
```

Any ideas as to why this my have been 'deprecated' on the live server? Perhaps there's some setting I've overlooked/forgotten that is causing the widgets to switch off?

Comment: Found the cause, and a cure - if not the true solution...

For some reason, the jquery-ui script libraries were not being copied into the assets folder - so the jquery function to add the autocomplete tags could not be found.

By copying the js files from dev to live server (in the assets subdirectory), it is now working again - but not clear why the framework is not doing its 'librarian' duties correctly.

Comment: You can try use `registerCoreScript()` method for registering `jquery-ui`
More information:(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCoreScript-detail)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check for errors in the Yii log file. I think that your web-server's process can not gain access to write in assets directory. If you have linux-based server, try to run this command:

`chmod -R 0777 path/to/your/assets`